# Regular expression not match in nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am writing a rewrite rule for nginx but keep getting loop issue
How do I write the regex to only match `?page=home` but stops at `?page=m-home`

This is what I have right now, but doesn't really work

```
if ($args ~ page=[^m\-](.+)){
  set $a $1;
  rewrite ^(.+)$ /cms/index.php?page=m-$a permanent;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why my previous answer did not suit your need, but actually it gave you a hint how to prevent a loop: use `break` instead of `permanent` (since your regex will match after the replacement, you get a loop).

Comment: I don't know why, but your answer doesn't work... I think it's due to rewrite doesn't operate on query parameters.